# java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String when invoking a EJB Bean Method

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, classcastexception

I've faced with the problem. I've successfully lookuped my remote bean from JBoss, but when I try to invoke any of its method next exception is about to appear:

```
java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String.
```

Full stack trace is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ProtocolMessageHandler.readAttachments(ProtocolMessageHandler.java:56)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.InvocationExceptionResponseHandler$MethodInvocationExceptionResultProducer.getResult(InvocationExceptionResponseHandler.java:85)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:212)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:214)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(ReceiverInterceptor.java:96)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:203)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:341)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:126)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:107)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:90)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.createEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.mypackage.FacadeImpl.createEvent(FacadeImpl.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.createEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Last row is the invocation of my method called "CreateEvent".
I guess the exception is throwned inside "getResult()" method of EJBClientInvocationContext.

My code is:

```
IEventDao eventDao = (IEventDao) ctx.lookup("java:/task/EventDao!MyPackage.IEventDao");
```

EventDao has been successfully gotten from the remote.
Trying to invoke a method:

```
public Event createEvent(final Event event) {
    return eventDao.createEvent(event);
}

Event event = new EventImpl("Test event: Star Wars: Episode VI");
createEvent(event); <-- Line #89. Exception has been throwned.
```

CreateEvent method body. But just for your info: it's not even enter this piece of code. It throwns the exception before even invoking `entityManager.persist(event);`

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Event createEvent(Event event) {
    entityManager.persist(event);
    return event;
}
```

Here is the full code of FacadeImpl:

```
@Service
public class FacadeImpl implements BookingFacade {
@Autowired
private FacadeUtils facadeUtils;
private IEventDao eventDao;  
private InitialContext ctx;
private Properties props = new Properties();

public void init() throws NamingException, IOException {
    props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jndi.properties"));
    ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    eventDao = (IEventDao) ctx.lookup("java:/Assignment16-1.0-SNAPSHOT/EventDao!com.mypackage.IEventDao");      
}

public Event createEvent(final Event event) {
    return eventDao.createEvent(event);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us `createEvent` implementation? Also, show us what happens in `FacadeImpl.java:89`. The error comes from a cast, do you do any in your code other than shown?

Comment: I have added all the info you requested. Thank you for your quick respond!

Comment: Can you please post the full class (not only the method call) of `FacadeImpl`? I think we are missing something important.

Comment: I have added the full code of FacadeImpl.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String` is due to bad use of generics, or trying to downcast (e.g. Object -> String) to an incompatible type. Remember, you cannot assign an Object type to String type without explicit type-cast amd the object should be castable to String.

This is a good post for troubleshooting ClassCastException: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-classcastexception-how-to-solve-class-cast-exception/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I posted all the code that I have. All this code has worked like charm before I started to use EJB and get the bean with JNDI lookup.

Comment: com.mypackage.FacadeImpl.createEvent(FacadeImpl.java:89) - this line is trying to cast "something" into String type, but it fails due to type incompatibility. I saw ur FacadeImpl code, but it doesnt seem to be full code (there are hardly 15 lines in the post, while the exception is on line 89). I want to know: 1) the line that causes exception 2) all the variables this line uses and how they are created 3) if it is a method call, then signature of the method it is trying to call. Check for type compatibilities

Comment: There are 5 more methods, but they are not invoked, I dont use them right now, 89 line is the line which I have showed you in the FacadeImpl code. The question is: what and why do they program want to cast? I dont get it. Thanky you for you answer!

Comment: From the exception stack trace, it seems that the code in FacadeImpl.craeteEvent is invoked and the exception is thrown from the createEvent method of FacadeImpl. If Facadeimpl.craeteEvent method is only invoking 'eventDao.createEvent(event)', then better check the types used in this line, as I suspect the exception may be thrown from this line, in contrast to what you have indicated in your post.